# Flutter calendar adding event 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart': Failed assertion: line 15 pos 15: 'date != null': is not true

Tags: android, flutter, dart, calendar

I have a project and there is a calendar inside it. I am trying to add an event to chosen date when I click into a button.When I click it there is a little widget that opens and you enter a text and there is two buttons that is called add and cancel. When I click add it has to add as an event and display on the screen. But I get the error of 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart': Failed assertion: line 15 pos 15: 'date != null': is not true. I can't see where is the problem. Can you help me with that?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
//import 'package:medicine_reminder/src/ui/calendar/event.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _currentDate2 = DateTime.now();
  String _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(DateTime.now());
  DateTime _targetDateTime = DateTime.now();

  String title;

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
  DateTime selectedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime focusedDay = DateTime.now();

  TextEditingController _eventController = TextEditingController();

  CalendarCarousel _calendarCarouselNoHeader;

  static Widget _eventIcon = new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.person,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  );

  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(
    events: {
      new DateTime(2020, 2, 10): [
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 14),
          title: 'Event 1',
          icon: _eventIcon,
          dot: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 5.0,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 2',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 15),
          title: 'Event 3',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ),
      ],
    },
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2020, 2, 25),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 25),
          title: 'Event 5',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2020, 2, 10),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 4',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.addAll(new DateTime(2019, 2, 11), [
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 1',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 2',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 3',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _calendarCarouselNoHeader = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      todayBorderColor: Color(0xFF3EB16F),
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate2 = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      daysHaveCircularBorder: true,
      showOnlyCurrentMonthDate: false,
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
      weekFormat: false,
//      firstDayOfWeek: 4,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: 420.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      targetDateTime: _targetDateTime,
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateCustomShapeBorder:
          CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow)),
      markedDateCustomTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      showHeader: false,
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),

      todayButtonColor: Colors.yellow,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      prevDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
      inactiveDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.tealAccent,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
      onCalendarChanged: (DateTime date) {
        this.setState(() {
          _targetDateTime = date;
          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
        });
      },
      onDayLongPressed: (DateTime date) {
        print('long pressed date $date');
      },
    );

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 90,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3EB16F),
          title: Text("Calendar"),
          centerTitle: true,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 44, fontFamily: "Angel"),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              //custom icon

              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 30.0,
                  bottom: 16.0,
                  left: 16.0,
                  right: 16.0,
                ),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                      _currentMonth,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('PREV'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(
                              _targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month - 1);
                          _currentMonth =
                              DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('NEXT'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(
                              _targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month + 1);
                          _currentMonth =
                              DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _calendarCarouselNoHeader,
              ), //
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Add Event"),
              content: TextFormField(
                controller: _eventController,
              ),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) {
                    } else {
                      if (selectedEvents[selectedDay] != null) {
                        selectedEvents[selectedDay].add(
                          Event(title: _eventController.text),
                        );
                      } else {
                        selectedEvents[selectedDay] = [
                          Event(title: _eventController.text)
                        ];
                      }
                    }

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    _eventController.clear();
                    setState(() {});
                    return;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3EB16F),
          label: Text("Add"),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It is an awesome widget. But there is no good documentation for it. Me too having similar issue!